# Exporting hive table with headers using insert overwrite

Tags: hive

I want to export hive table data to a `json` file with headers.
I have written a shell script for exporting hive table data as a `json` file, but I want the headers to come along with the data.
I am using insert overwrite to solve this.

Here is my script,

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true ; 
insert overwrite local directory '/home/zeas/Chaitra/result' 
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE  select * from zeas.demo_airline_data_dataset"
```

Even though I have `set hive.cli.print.header=true;`, headers are not coming along.
Is there any way to get headers along with data using insert overwrite?

Comment: hive.cli.print.header=true  is for printing header in CLI output not in file ..

Comment: Then how can i get headers?

Comment: and Json file does not have any headed... it have key value pair..

Answer (score 0):

With beeline, you can use `--showheader=true` to see the header and this is also default if you don't write `--showheader=false` .

If you still don't see it, then you can get only the header using the similar query like the below one and write that into your output file before writing the content

```
header=`<BEELINE_CONN_STRING> --silent=true --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV=<delimiter> -e "set tez.queue.name=<queuename>; use <database_name>; select * from <table_name> limit 0;"`
```

Below line is to remove the table_name as we generally don't want the table names in final outputs

```
echo $header | sed "s/<table_name>.//g" >> ${final_output_file}
```